Answer to a poor quality question, alternate solutions are welcomed
Actually I saw a question on this site but due to its poor quality can't post the answer to that question on the original post. This is the original post essentially asking for $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_1^n\frac{x^{4} + 2x^{2} + 1}{\left(x^{\frac{113}{25}} + \frac{11}{3}x^{\frac{63}{25}} + 11x^{\frac{13}{25}}\right)^{5}}\mathrm{d}x$$ as a rational in lowest terms and the number of divisors of the numerator.
You all are free to give alternate solutions to this problem and let me present you with my solution. I'll also post the link of this question on the original one.

Here, we will first evaluate the integral and then the limit.
Let $$A=\int\frac{x^{4} + 2x^{2} + 1}{\left(x^{\frac{113}{25}} + \frac{11x^{\frac{63}{25}}}{3} + 11x^{\frac{13}{25}}\right)^{5}}\mathrm{d}x$$
A little bit of simplification yields $$A= \int \frac{243 \left(x^{4} + 2x^{2} + 1\right)}{x^{\frac{13}{5}} \left(3x^{4} + 11x^{2} + 33\right)^{5}} \, \mathrm{d}x$$
Substitute $u=x^{\frac{2}{5}}$ and get $$A= \frac{243×5}{2} \, \int \frac{u^{10} + 2u^{5} + 1}{u^{5} \left(3u^{10} + 11u^{5} + 33\right)^{5}} \, \mathrm{d}u$$
Now substitute $v = u \left(3u^{10} + 11u^{5} + 33\right)$ and get $$A= \frac{243×5}{33×2} \, \int \frac{1}{v^{5}} \, \mathrm{d}v$$
Now when $x=1$ then $u$ is also $=1$ and when $u=1$ then $v=47$ 
So the lower limit of integration of the last integral is $47$
And naturally the upper limit will come as $\infty$
Now $$\int_{47}^{\infty}\frac{1}{v^5}\mathrm{d}v=\frac{1}{19518724}$$
So we have $$A=\frac{243×5}{33×2×19518724}=\frac{405}{429411928}$$
Hence we get that $$\boxed{p=405}$$
And it's easy to see that the positive divisors of $405$ are $1, 3, 5, 9, 15, 27, 45, 81, 135, 405$ and hence the number of positive divisors of $p$ aka $405$ is $$\boxed{\color{red}{10}}$$

Direct substitution
Let $v=3x^{\frac{22}{5}}+11x^{\frac{12}{5}}+33x^{\frac{2}{5}}$  , then $$
d v=\frac{66}{5} x^{-\frac{3}{5}}\left(x^4+2 x^2+1\right) d x
$$
Hence $$
\begin{aligned}
 \int\frac{x^{4} + 2x^{2} + 1}{\left(x^{\frac{113}{25}} + \frac{11}{3}x^{\frac{63}{25}} + 11x^{\frac{13}{25}}\right)^{5}}\mathrm{d}x&=\frac{5}{66} \int \frac{d v}{x^{\left(-\frac{3}{25}\right)^5}\left(x^{\frac{113}{25}}+\frac{11 x^{\frac{65}{35}}}{3}+11 x^{\frac{13}{25}}\right)^5} \\
& =\frac{5}{66} \int \frac{d v}{\left(x^{\frac{22}{5}}+\frac{11}{3} x^{\frac{12}{5}}+11 x^{\frac{2}{5}}\right)^5} \\
& =\frac{5 \times 81}{22} \int \frac{d v}{v^5}\\&=-\frac{5 \times 81}{22 \times 6 v^6}
\end{aligned}
$$
